# CMD command (XCOPY,MOVE,ROBOCOPY) to Replicate "CUT and PASTE" in Windows OS (pref. 7)

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy, robocopy

our Users has a Manual process that CUTS and PASTE files from one SHARED folder to another SHARED Folder over the network. The manual process has no problem except that it can be done automatically by means of a Batch CMD coding. Now I was tasked to do this but I failed in some way due to several requirements:

1. The File Ownership (OWNER) remains
2. The Time Stamp is retained

What I did so far:

```
xcopy "\\sharedpc\folderA\*.CSV" "\\sharedpc\folderB\" /O
robocopy "\\sharedpc\folderA" "\\sharedpc\folderB" *.csv /COPY:DO
robocopy "\\sharedpc\folderA" "\\sharedpc\folderB" *.csv /COPY:DTO
```

I am getting access denied from these commands when I run them (ELEVATED Already).

I am guessing that the either folderA or folderB or the share permissions is strictly set to read/write without the Special Permissions, because I can easily do these commands without access denied on my PUBLIC Shared Folder.

What cannot be done:

1. Grant Special Permission for those folders for Users

The weirdest part is, they can do CUT and PASTE but cannot run my batch command properly with Elevated Permissions.

My question is, **How can I replicate the CUT and PASTE using Batch CMD?**

Answer (score 0):

You may work around it by mapping drive letters to the shares using credentials that do have permissions - but then you have to supply the credentials.

Comment: well thats is the problem. SA Team cannot grant special permissions for users. I just want to help them speeden up the process. SA is also telling me if they can Cut and paste, why cant the command replicate it. Im at loss here. The move command does not retain ownership too.